# Napierian logarithm with BASH

Tags: bash

I would like to compute a Napierian logarithm with Bash.

Here is my code using what I found in the internet. The values I use are in output files.

```
for nn in 1 2 3 4 ; do
        for w in 0.5 ; do
                a=`grep '  @ Final variational ensemble-DFT energy:      ' $nn"_"$w.out`
                for n in 1000 ; do
                    b=`grep '  @ Final variational ensemble-DFT energy:      ' $n"_"$w.out`
                done
        done
        c=`echo "l({$a - $b})" | bc -l`
        d=`echo "l({$nn})" | bc -l`
        echo $d"        "$c  >> data_slope.dat
done
```

I want to plot $d = f($c) from data_slope.dat, but apparently this notation with bc -l doesn't work for me.

I obtain this kind of error :

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: @
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Whereas I've already done some bash code like this without trying to compute a logarithm, and I didn't get those errors.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What are you expecting `$a` and `$b` to contain? And how is `bc` supposed to understand it?

Comment: What does your input file look like? You're going to have strip the labels you are matching from `a` and `b` before you can use them as numbers.

Comment: Shellcheck is great but it doesn't really help with the actual problem here as the problem isn't with the shell script itself.

Comment: Could you maybe use `echo "9999999.5*(16.11809565-l(x))" |bc -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax errors are reported by `bc`. Its syntax for subtraction expects numbers on both sides of the `-` operand, not strings containing `@`. The curly braces are wrong, too: you can experiment with

```
a=3
b=0.2
for expression in "l($a-$b)" "l({$a-$b})" "({@F - @T})" ; do
    echo "$expression"
    echo "$expression" | bc -l
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comments I manage to find my mistake.

@Etan Reisner : Indeed my a and b are wrong, I did not grep the values of a and b but the sentence before the values... I should have put ${a:47:16} instead of $a to grep the value of a, which is a real number. Same for $b.

@choroba : I removed the curly braces, now it works.